# Socktet io, JavaScript data not updating itself in table

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io

I'm currently making a website where the data in table update in every second but in my case its not working please help me i need to update my table like this website:

I need that my data is also update every second.

I used everything but didn't got success.:

I need that my data is also update every second.

I used everything but didn't got success.

Here is my code.

```js
var roundSymbol = ["GOLD", "GOLDM", "SILVER", "SILVERM","SILVERMIC", "CRUDEOIL", "CRUDEOILM","COTTON"];
var stockData = [];
var currentStock = [];

function renderStockDataTable()
{
    try
    {
        //stockData['data'] = _.where(stockData['data'], { Exchange: "MCX" });

        for (var i = 0; i < stockData['data'].length; i++) {
            if (roundSymbol.indexOf(stockData['data'][i]['Symbol']) > -1) {
                for (var key in stockData['data'][i]) {
                    if (key != 'Symbol' && key != 'Ser/Exp' && key != 'Exchange'
                        && key != 'LTPNormal'
                        && key != 'LTPRed'
                        && key != 'LTPGreen') {
                        stockData['data'][i][key] =
                            parseFloat(stockData['data'][i][key]);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (parseFloat(stockData['data'][i]['Net Change In Rs']) > 0) {
                if (stockData['data'][i]['Net Change In Rs'].toString().indexOf("+") == -1) {
                    stockData['data'][i]['Net Change In Rs'] = "+" + stockData['data'][i]['Net Change In Rs'];
                }
                stockData['data'][i]['GreenChange'] = true;
                stockData['data'][i]['RedChange'] = false;
                stockData['data'][i]['NormalChange'] = false;
            }
            else if (parseFloat(stockData['data'][i]['Net Change In Rs']) < 0) {
                stockData['data'][i]['RedChange'] = true;
                stockData['data'][i]['GreenChange'] = false;
                stockData['data'][i]['NormalChange'] = false;
            }
            else {
                stockData['data'][i]['GreenChange'] = false;
                stockData['data'][i]['RedChange'] = false;
                stockData['data'][i]['NormalChange'] = true;
            }
        }


        var stockTemplate = $('#stockTemplate').html();
        Mustache.parse(stockTemplate);
        var rendered = Mustache.render(stockTemplate, stockData);
        $('#stockBody').html(rendered);

        setTimeout(() => {
            $('.red').removeClass('red');
            $('.green').removeClass('green');
        }, 1000);
    }
    catch(e) {}
}

function initData()
{
    $('#lastUpdate').val(new Date().toLocaleString());
    $.get("", function (data) {
        stockData = data;

        try {
            for (var i = 0; i < stockData['data'].length; i++) {
                stockData['data'][i]['LTPNormal'] = true;
                stockData['data'][i]['LTPGreen'] = false;
                stockData['data'][i]['LTPRed'] = false;
            }

            $('#lastUpdate').text(new Date().toLocaleString());
            renderStockDataTable();
        }
        catch (e) { }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    initData();

    var socket = io('');
    socket.on("recieveStock", (data) => {
        if (
            data != undefined &&
            data.differences != undefined &&
            data.differences != null
        ) {
            $('#lastUpdate').text(new Date().toLocaleString());
            currentStock = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(stockData));

            if (stockData != undefined && stockData != null
                && stockData['data'] != undefined
                && stockData['data'] != null) {
                for (var i = 0; i < stockData['data'].length; i++) {
                    var changeObj = _.findWhere(data.differences, {
                        Symbol: stockData['data'][i]["Symbol"],
                        "Ser/Exp": stockData['data'][i]["Ser/Exp"]
                    });

                    stockData['data'][i]['LTPNormal'] = true;
                    stockData['data'][i]['LTPGreen'] = false;
                    stockData['data'][i]['LTPRed'] = false;

                    if (changeObj != undefined) {
                        if (changeObj['Last Traded Price'] != undefined) {
                            if (parseFloat(changeObj['Last Traded Price']) > parseFloat(stockData['data'][i]['Last Traded Price'])) {
                                stockData['data'][i]['LTPNormal'] = false;
                                stockData['data'][i]['LTPGreen'] = true;
                                stockData['data'][i]['LTPRed'] = false;
                            }
                            else if (parseFloat(changeObj['Last Traded Price']) < parseFloat(stockData['data'][i]['Last Traded Price'])) {
                                stockData['data'][i]['LTPNormal'] = false;
                                stockData['data'][i]['LTPGreen'] = false;
                                stockData['data'][i]['LTPRed'] = true;
                            }
                            else {
                                stockData['data'][i]['LTPNormal'] = true;
                                stockData['data'][i]['LTPGreen'] = false;
                                stockData['data'][i]['LTPRed'] = false;
                            }
                        }

                        for (var key in changeObj) {
                            if (key != "Symbol" && key != "Ser/Exp" && key != 'Exchange' && key != 'LTPNormal'
                                && key != 'LTPRed'
                                && key != 'LTPGreen') {
                                stockData['data'][i][key] = changeObj[key];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            renderStockDataTable();
        }
    });

})

$(window).focus(function () {
    initData();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mixing up socket.io and GET requests the url you are using as the socket.io connection (http://88.99.61.159:4000/getData) is a GET request page you should use AJAX to create a request and then use the data that is returned to make updates to your table.

These errors here are telling you there is no socket connection on the server.
[image]

```
  setInterval(() => {
    $.get('http://88.99.61.159:4000/getData', function(data, status){
      // do something with data
      alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
  }, 1000)
```

Comment: initData() function working fine it update the data in table for first time but after it in document.ready() function it's not updating the data every second using socket io

Comment: yea thats because the ip you are using is not a socket connection its a get page do me a favor and put `http://88.99.61.159:4000/getData` in your url bar and press enter if it was a socket connection you would not be able to see that data. sockets do not work like this sockets connect to an IP and register with the servers socket connection and then with that creates a event based communication between client and server.

Comment: I tried this url also http://88.99.61.159:4000  and http://88.99.61.159:4000/getdata I think that the first one is work with socket.io please check it.

Comment: still no connection from the server who is running the server?? is it your server?? someone else's server? if it is yours are you sure there is a socket.io installed on it? I dont think its your server because if you open the `88.99.61.159:4000` in the url it refuses the connection.

Comment: Thats not even your code that you are trying to debug . . . your asking other people to help you steal code i'm glad it doesn't work they put in checks specifically so you cannot take their code so if your are not willing to take the time to learn and code it yourself then. nobody here is going to help you. I gave you a work around and if you are to lazy to implement or even attempt it then good luck. well you can take their code but you cannot use their socket connections.